# ionic 5 - ngFor not showing data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I tried all ways to display data from the database. Data is coming from the database however it doesn't display any records on the UI. When i print the console.log for data, it comes correctly. Following are the code segments that i have used and i am completely new the ionic development, so kindly point if i made any blunders.

### tab3.page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      User List
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-button expand="block" (click)="getData()" >Get All users</ion-button>  
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let Users of UserList">
            <h2>Hello {{ UserList[Users].fullname.value }}</h2>
            <p item-right> {{Users["email"]}}</p>
            <p>{{Users.phone_no}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

### tab3.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController, AlertController, LoadingController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {} from '../Login/tab1.module';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { setIndex } from '@ionic-native/core/decorators/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {

    UserList:any[];
    LoginName:string = ""; 
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad(){
      console.log("Getting Users");
      this.getData(); 
    }

    getData()
    {
      this.http.get("http://localhost/MyFirstApp/GetAllUsers.php")
        .subscribe(
          data => {
                    let UserList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log(UserList);
                    console.log(UserList[1].fullname);
                    let i=0;
                    for (let Users in UserList){
                        this.LoginName = UserList[Users].fullname;
                    } 

                  }, 
          err => {
                    console.log(err);
                  }
      ); 
    }


}
```

Data is coming correctly from Database in console.log window

```
UserList[
0: {fullname: "shubham", email: "shubham@gmail.com", phone_no: "1230235420"}
1: {fullname: "johan", email: "johan@gmail.com", phone_no: "120356452"}
2: {fullname: "aditya", email: "aditya@gmail.com", phone_no: "120356452"}
]
```

Comment: Just try editing your *ngFor as follows 
`<ion-item *ngFor="let user of UserList">
            <h2>Hello {{ user.fullname}}</h2>
            <p item-right> {{user.email]}}</p>
            <p>{{user.phone_no}}</p>
      </ion-item>`

Comment: You're not setting the class level variable `UserList` to anything. As a matter of fact, you `let` a variable of the same name inside the `subscribe`. Plus, your template code is not right. Not sure why this is getting up-votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three main things:

1. You have used `let` which is a block scope, hence would not be reflected in the class.

   **Solution:**
   Change `let UserList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`
   to `this.UserList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`.
2. You have a binding issue, since you are not placing the index in array value, but instead are passing an object value.

   **Solution:**
   Change `{{ UserList[Users].fullname.value }}`
   to `{{Users.fullname}}`.
3. You have only type annotated the `UserList` object, since it is used to iterate.

   **Solution:**
   Change `UserList:any[];`
   to `UserList:any[]=[];`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some wrong reference to the variables. I guess only `phone_no` should be displaying. You are referencing as arrays, but they are part of a JSON Object.

The right way should be:

```
{{Users.fullname}}
{{Users.email}}
{{Users.phone_no}}
```

And, as final note, please **DO NOT** name variables starting with capital letter. Let be `user` instead of `User`. Capital letters for classes only. Maybe, and I say maybe, the code is trying to look for `Users` class, and that is why it is not working....